# What is the actual use of GAN model? Is it only used to generate the data that closely resembles original dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, gan, tensor

I am very new to tensor flow. I came across GANS. From what I understand in GANs there are 2 models, Generator and Discriminator. Generator job is to generate the data that will be able to fool the discriminator by producing data which closely resembles actual data (distribution of data). And we have Discriminator whose job is to tell if the data came from fake/generator or real/actual input data. In ideal situation, discriminator will not be able to tell if the data came from generator or real data set.

This is what I understood GANS does. What I don't understand is what exactly is done after we have perfec Generator/Discriminator. Is it used just to produce extra data in case we have few data or is it used solely generate data to create fake result. Most of the implementation I have seen are in image classification where generator creates similar data ( mnist) dataset.

In short. What do we do after we have generator/discriminator? What exactly is it used for other than creating "fake" data?

Thanks, 
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of a well-trained GAN is that you can create an unlimited amount of data that is indistinguishable from the "real" data you are modeling. From such a lot of synthetic data, you can derive many quantities of interest. If you need a prediction for the expectation of some quantity, just generate data and take its mean. If you need a quantile prediction, take the quantile from your generated data. And so forth.

For instance, I work in forecasting supermarket sales. I have not yet seen anyone use GANs for this, but if we could generate a large amount of "sales" for a future situation (e.g., promotion X three days before Christmas) that approximates the actual distribution of sales closely enough, we could take a 98% quantile and fill the shelves up to this amount, ensuring an adequate safety stock.

Comment: Thank you for your response, so is my assumption correct on thinking that GAN is used to reproduce fake data that can be used to train the another model in case we have less original data? So is generator the end product that will be used by other model? I have yet to see any implementation where GAN data is used for prediction? If you have a example, I would really appreciate it if you could direct me in that direction. Thank you

Comment: I am not an expert in GANs, and no, I have not seen anyone use the output as an input to another model. I suspect this would not work very well.

Comment: If we can't use the output as an input to another model, how would the ability to generate unlimited amount of data help in the process? I am sorry I am just trying to understand the process.

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes. I did but in comment, you mentioned that you would suspect that feeding generated data wouldn't work well. Does it not contradict what you mentioned in your original comment where you mentioned that you would be able to use that data to forcast the future sell and fill the shelves accordingly?

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with feeding the data into another *model*.

Comment: @StephanKolassa maybe it's not 100% of the input values, but GANs certainly can and have been used for data augmentation for another model, e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-52737-x (CycleGANs + segmentation model).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you.

Comment: @jkm Thank you for this paper. It seems the combination of the generated graph and actual data is possible to train another model.